# Tranlasting C code into MIPS assembler, with functions as function parameters

Tags: c, assembly, memory, mips

I'm going to translate such C code in to MIPS:

```
int call(int arg)
{
    return foo(arg+10) + bar(arg) + baz(one(), two(arg-1), arg);
}
```

My MIPS implementation is:

```
.data
.text
.globl callMany

callMany:
    add   $s1, $a0,$zero          
    addi  $a0, $a0, 10
    jal foo
    add  $s0, $v0, $zero    #s0 = foo(arg+10)

    add   $a0, $s1, $zero
    jal bar
    add  $s0, $s0, $v0      #s0 = foo(arg+10)+bar(arg)
    addiu $sp, $sp, -8
    jal one                  
    sw    $v0, 0($sp)       #save one()
    addi $a0, $s1, -1
    jal two
    sw    $v0, 4($sp)       #save two(arg-1)

    lw    $a0, 0($sp)
    lw    $a1, 4($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 8
    add   $a2, $s1, $zero
    jal baz

    add  $s0, $s0, $v0 # Runtime exception at 0x004009d0: arithmetic overflow
    add  $v0, $s0, $zero
    jr  $ra
```

I don't know why I have an error on:

```
add  $s0, $s0, $v0 # Runtime exception at 0x004009d0: arithmetic overflow
```

since what I'm doing in this line of code is:

```
s0 = foo(arg+10) + bar(arg) + (the return value of baz)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `addu` to avoid overflow. Note your code is broken in other ways too. But that wasn't your question, so :)

Comment: So could you be more specific about the "broken" part, because what I know there's something wrong with my code that cause the overflow. Even with addu, the code is still wrong, and that's not I'm asking. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through it in a debugger?  I notice that you `jr $ra` without restoring `$ra` after `jal`, creating an infinite loop.  (This is probably why `add` inside that loop eventually overflows.)  You would have seen this if you used a debugger.

Comment: That's a gruesome piece of C; translating it into assembler won't improve its clarity.  Can you actually call two functions and add three values all in a single line of assembler? I haven't come across a machine with that powerful a CPU.  Or you've not stated what you're really doing on that line.